# type() call causing 'int object is not callable' error

Tags: python

I have been trying to check the type of an object and have been getting an ''int' object is not callable' error. As a test I have even removed the object completely and have replaced it with a constant, and am still getting the error.

This is pyqgis code but I don't think the GIS aspect is particularly relevant. I believe the issue is one of Python logic/syntax. This is the problem line:

```
QgsMessageLog.logMessage(type('1'), level=Qgis.Info)
```

I would have expected this to tell me that '1' is a string, but instead I get the error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

From what I know of this error I would have expected that this means that 'type' also exists as a property, but it doesn't as far as I am aware.

Comment: You probably have assigned to `type` somewhere before this code. Maybe you should provide a [mcve]?

Comment: What is your IDE?

Comment: IDE = Notepad++ :-)

Comment: Oh god. That's not an IDE. You really need some better editor, that's gonna make your life really difficult. You'll really appreciate things like autocomplete and syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yes, point taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it means you've defined `type` somewhere earlier in your code. For example:

```
type = 1
print(type('1'))
```

You can resolve the issue by not shadowing built-in names.

Comment: Resolved!  Silly mistake on my part. I had indeed used 'type' as a variable. (I wrote the code a while ago and have only now come to debug it.) Many thanks for the quick responses.